# Why am I getting "TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)"?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've created a `time_zones` table. When I try to populate it I get a `TypeError` saying I need to include an `id` value.

The table from postgresql:

```
\d+ time_zones
                                                         Table "public.time_zones"
   Column   |            Type             |                        Modifiers                        | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id         | integer                     | not null default nextval('time_zones_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 name       | character varying(128)      | not null                                                | extended |              | 
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |                                                         | plain    |              | 
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |                                                         | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "time_zones_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "time_zones_name_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (name)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "app_users" CONSTRAINT "app_users_time_zone_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (time_zone_id) REFERENCES time_zones(id)
```

The TimeZone class from `models.py`:

```
class TimeZone(db.Model):
  __table_name__ = 'time_zones'

  id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('time_zones_id_seq'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
  name = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
  created_at = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP(timezone=False), default=_get_date)
  updated_at = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP(timezone=False), onupdate=_get_date)
```

The `Alembic` migration file:

```
def upgrade():
  op.create_table('time_zones',
                  sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
                  sa.Column('name', sa.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True),
                  sa.Column('created_at', sa.TIMESTAMP(timezone=False), default=_get_date),
                  sa.Column('updated_at', sa.TIMESTAMP(timezone=False), onupdate=_get_date))
```

My attempt to add a name to the `time_zones` table via the flask shell with the `TypeError`:

```
>>> from app.main.models import TimeZone
>>> from app import db
>>> 
>>> tz = TimeZone(name='Central Time (US & Canada)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 347, in _new_state_if_none
    state = self._state_constructor(instance, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 747, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/instrumentation.py", line 177, in _state_constructor
    self.dispatch.first_init(self, self.class_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 256, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2860, in _event_on_first_init
    configure_mappers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2756, in configure_mappers
    mapper._post_configure_properties()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1710, in _post_configure_properties
    prop.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/interfaces.py", line 183, in init
    self.do_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1612, in do_init
    self._process_dependent_arguments()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/relationships.py", line 1637, in _process_dependent_arguments
    setattr(self, attr, attr_value())
TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

### UPDATE

If I remove the relationship from my AppUser class in `app.auth.models` I do not get this error any more. So I must not have my relationship setup properly.

Here is the `models.py` im the `auth` module:

```
class AppUser(UserMixin, Base):
  __tablename__ = 'app_users'

  username = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)
  firstname = db.Column(db.String(128))
  lastname = db.Column(db.String(128))
  email = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
  phone = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(12))
  company = db.Column(db.String(32))
  password_hash = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

  # When I kill these two lines I do not get the error.
  #time_zone_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('time_zones.id', ondelete='cascade'))
  #time_zone = db.relationship('TimeZone', backref='app_users', order_by=id)

  def __init__(self, username, email, password, firstname, lastname, company, phone):
    self.username = username.lower()
    self.email = email.lower()
    self.firstname = firstname.title()
    self.lastname = lastname.title()
    self.company = company
    self.phone = phone
    #self.time_zone_id = time_zone_id
    self.set_password(password)


  def set_password(self, password):
    self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

  def verify_password(self, password):
    return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

  def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

Comment: give the field a different name.

Comment: Your appusers table does not contain a primary key. postgres demands unique constrains inside a table_args field.  I think that's why your app is crashing. Try putting a single file app where we can test your problem.

Comment: And I am not sure why you are using db.Sequence

Comment: Use this gist as a template for creating a reproductive app for us to test. https://gist.github.com/3450f383e41931162f19

Comment: @CESCO, it's getting the id from `Base`. Why not use `db.Sequence`?

Answer (score 4):

## Suspected problem

I just solved a similar problem in my own code where the problem was with the `order_by=id` on the line defining the relationship that you commented out in your "UPDATE". When you declare the ordering that way, SQLAlchemy tries to use the `id` attribute of AppUser to do the ordering since the declaration is within the AppUser class. Since AppUser has no column or other property called 'id', python accesses the builtin id() method instead, which can't be used without an argument (and wouldn't be useful for ordering the relationship anyway).

## Proposed solution

I would bet that changing the order_by parameter to `order_by=TimeZone.id` or `order_by="TimeZone.id"` would clear the error; a similar change fixed the problem in my code.

Comment: The exact reason is that [`order_by`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.order_by) and the like accept Python-evaluable strings *or functions* for lazy evaluation. Since `id` is the latter, SQLAlchemy tries to call it (with 0 arguments) during mapper initialization in order to produce the actual expression to order by.